# Importance Sampling - Value at Risk in Matlab

Tags: matlab, sampling

I would like to integrate importance sampling in monte carlo to speed up the calculation.
Here I have created a simple example in matlab:

```
a=randn(10,10000);
a_sum=sum(a,1);
quantile(a_sum, 0.01)
```

The value at risk will amount to  -7.3159 and around 100 scenarios are above the value at risk. So using a shift of -1. I can have more scenarios above value at risk:

```
b=a-1;
b_sum=sum(b,1);
```

A common way to calculate the value at risk is to use the likelihood ratios. Since I have shifted each random number by -1, I can calculate for each shift the likelihood ratio. But can I combine these likelihood ratios? And how can I calculate the value at risk?

Comment: Are you asking what the cumulative distribution function of a N(-0.1,1) distributed value is? Either way this does not appear to be much of a programming question. Please make sure you know what to do 'on paper', then we can help you how to do it 'on the pc'.